# Need help! - Unable to load JSON using COPY command

Tags: json, postgresql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

Need your expertise here!

I am trying to load a `JSON` file (generated by `JSON` dumps) into `redshift` using copy command which is in the following format,

```
[
{
    "cookieId": "cb2278", 
    "environment": "STAGE", 
    "errorMessages": [
        "70460"
    ]
}
,
{
    "cookieId": "cb2271", 
    "environment": "STG", 
    "errorMessages": [
        "70460"
    ]
}
]
```

We ran into the error - "Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object."

when I tried to get rid of square braces - [] and remove the "," comma separator between `JSON` dicts then it loads perfectly fine.

```
{
    "cookieId": "cb2278", 
    "environment": "STAGE", 
    "errorMessages": [
        "70460"
    ]
}

{
    "cookieId": "cb2271", 
    "environment": "STG", 
    "errorMessages": [
        "70460"
    ]
}
```

But in reality most `JSON` files from API s have this formatting.
I could do string replace or reg ex to get rid of , and [] but I am wondering if there is a better way to load into `redshift` seamlessly with out modifying the file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert a JSON array into a stream of the array's elements is to pipe the former into `jq '.[]'`.  The output is sent to stdout.

If the JSON array is in a file named input.json, then the following command will produce a stream of the array's elements on stdout:

```
$ jq ".[]" input.json
```

If you want the output in jsonlines format, then use the -c switch (i.e. `jq -c ......`).

For more on jq, see https://stedolan.github.io/jq

Comment: Thanks @peak ! I am wondering if redshift has any feature to consume this format ? Also wondering if there is a pythonic way to load the second format into a dict ?   {
    "cookieId": "cb2278", 
    "environment": "STAGE", 
    "errorMessages": [
        "70460"
    ]
}

{
    "cookieId": "cb2271", 
    "environment": "STG", 
    "errorMessages": [
        "70460"
    ]
}